# Summing column values in table using arcgisscripting?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I need to create a python script that sums a column's values in a table. Thereafter, the script is supposed to get the percentage of each individual row in that column and populate this percentage values in a another column. I been struggling for quite some time now, I checked the net, but there is nothing of this sort. The nearest is an [ArcGIS Discussion Forum thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1728&t=241385), but its for an older version of ArcMap, or I am using it wrong.

```
import arcgisscripting, sys
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

intable = sys.argv[1]
field = sys.argv[2]

# Create search cursor
rows = gp.SearchCursor(intable)
row = rows.Next()
x = 0.0
# Enter while loop for each feature/row
while row:
    x += row.getvalue(field)
    print x
    row = rows.next()
#note value can be rounded depending on field type
gp.calculatefield(intable,sys.argv[3],float(x),"PYTHON")
```

Comment: which version of arc are you using? The solution posted below uses the [arcpy data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000008000000) which is only available from version 10.1 upwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
ctotal = sum([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("inputtable",["columnX","PercentColumn"])])#column total

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("inputtable",["columnX","PercentColumn"]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         row[1] = (row[0]/float(ctotal))*100
         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you so so much. It worked like a charm. 

I am new at this, can you please direct me to a link that can help me in learning as much python as possible. Especially that total line, that total was giving me trouble as in a for loop it would loose the value it retained initially. So when I use it in an equation, it would return the instantiated value of 0. 

I will await that link.. I am using arcmap10.1 by the way.

Comment: @Lazlo - refer to the [list comprehension section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) from the python tutorial

Comment: Is it possible to nest the SeachCursor line within UpdateCursor?
I am trying to create a tool that get a table as a parameter and calculate the previously stated. 
But when I use the SearchCursor outside of updateCursor, I get an error that states that the table does not exist. I am not sure if this is possible..your help would be appreciated greatly.